# Why is -1 not mapped to itself by Python's built-in hash function

Tags: python, hash, cpython

[image: Hash(-1) = -2]

It seems -1 is the only integer not mapped to itself by the built-in hash function in Python. What are the considerations behind this?

The fact that this intriguing problem has not attracted more attention is intriguing.

Comment: I think it's because `-1` is used by the CPython implementation to denote failures internally

Comment: Why would it be mapped to itself? Actually since a hash reduces a value to a fixed number of bits, there are collisions and thus there is an infinite number of integers that are not mapped to themselves: `hash(12345678901234567890)`.

Comment: Just for ref, it's hardcoded in the cpython source (a lot of if (x == -1) {x = -2}): https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/pyhash.c